# Spring boot: Point to different properties file from my main properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I point to different properties file from my main properties file depending on needs?

My main file contains different webservices types and where to find the **specific** file to each of them, where I will be able to access more information about that particular service.

I have a main properties file

webservices.properties:

> ```
> webs1=C:\Users\yyy\webs1.properties
> webs2=C:\Users\yyy\webs2.properties
> webs3=C:\Users\yyy\webs3.properties
> webs4=C:\Users\yyy\webs4.properties
> ```

inside the web services properties file

webs1.properties:

> ```
> key1=value1
> key2=value2
> key3=value3
> ```

Currently my application only uses one Webservice. I call its properties file with @PropertySource in the Config class. And then use the Environment.getProperty() method whenever I want to access one of the values.

How do I make it as such I call the specific properties file of the Webservice that I'm currently using?

Config.class

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:src/main/resources/sddv1.properties", name = "sample.props")
    @Configuration
    public class Config {
    
        @Autowired
        Environment env;
        
        @Bean
        public void doStuff() {
            String prop1 = env.getProperty(key1);
            // I want to loop through different webservices and use the method above on each of their properties files
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot because property files are meant to give you facility of keeping values dynamic and reading from a common location instead of `hardcoding`. Your app should be designed in such a way that any single property file you refer (Before app start) must have those properties. You can maintain different property files but at a time one is in effect using `spring.profiles.active`. However, if your specific property file does not have the value, spring will search in parent property file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard application-properties or use profiles.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.8/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles

Or just override the defined properties with environment variables.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.8/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config